# How to redirect to full URL when user type without www or control name in MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC4 based website. I want to set following functionalities.

> 1- When user type "mywebsite.com" or "http://mywebsite.com", website
>   should show "www.mywebsite.com"
>
> 2- When user type "mywebsite.com/Home" or "http://mywebsite.com/Home",
>   website should show "www.mywebsite.com"

Please suggest me for both of the cases.

Comment: this is an IIS setup

Comment: @Emil Can you please suggest me any link? it will be greatly helpful.

Comment: start here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2013/05/22/http-to-https-redirects-on-iis-7-x-and-higher/

Comment: @Emil I have done with first. I have tried to search for second but not getting. Can you please suggest for second one?